# Requesting and Showing an Integer from db Flask sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Im currently working in a simple SuperMarket list where you have 2 text inputs where they ask the product and price.
[Image of the program without Price Textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HMd0.png)

[Image of the both textfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFCux.png)

So when I ask for this 2 data inputs it gives me an error in my Super Route that is the one that validates the data.

```
@app.route('/super', methods=['POST'])
def add_super():
    content = request.form['content']
    #precio = request.form['precio']
    if not request.form['content'] or not request.form['precio']:
        flash('Debes ingresar un texto')
        return redirect('/')
    super = Super(content)
    #super = Super(precio)
    db.session.add(super)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Registro guardado con exito!')
    return redirect('/')
```

Here I added the price to request the data from the database so i can call it and show it later, but this is where i get the error.

This is how my DB is setup:

```
class Super(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    precio = db.Column(db.Integer)
    listo = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __init__(self, content,precio):
        self.content = content
        self.precio = precio
        self.listo = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Content %s>' % self.content
    # def __repr__(self):
    #      return '<Precio %s>' % self.precio
db.create_all()
```

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: Yes, in the console i get this error..  127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017 12:50:41] "POST /super HTTP/1.1" 500 - and in the web after i fill the text fields with data it goes to "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Super` takes 2 parameters in its `__init__`, but you only supply 1 parameter.

See for example what happens if we define in interpreter:

```
>>> class c1(object):
...     def __init__(self, p1, p2):
...         self.p1 = p1
...         self.p2 = p2
```

Then we try to create an instance using only one parameter:

```
>>> c1('spam')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

This is probably what happens when you do:

```
super = Super(content)
```

However, if we supply two parameters:

```
>>> c1('spam','eggs')
<__main__.c1 object at 0x7f64a2f3a350>
```

So you need to create `Super` instance with two arguments, like you probably intended:

```
super = Super(content, precio)
```

Speculating a bit, what you were after is probably something like this:

```
@app.route('/super', methods=['POST'])
def add_super():
    content = request.form.get('content')
    precio = request.form.get('precio')
    if precio is None or content is None:
        flash('Debes ingresar un texto')
        return redirect('/')
    super = Super(content, precio)
    db.session.add(super)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Registro guardado con exito!')
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: @CarlosNavarro Glad it helped, would you please mark as answered then?